# Target mobile phones

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, target

I want to target mobile devices using CSS media queries like this:

```
@media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       (min-resolution: 1.5dppx) {

   /* your retina rules here */
}
```

What would be the correct settings for mobile phones. Let's say I want to avoid targeting tablets and larger screens and target only mobile phones?

Answer (score 3):

Quote from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7354648/1479606):

```
min-width: 320px  // smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones
min-width: 481px  // portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide.
min-width: 641px  // portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 and 854x480 phones
min-width: 961px  // tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops
min-width: 1025px // big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops
min-width: 1281px // hi-res laptops and desktops
```

Comment: Why not close as a duplicate, then?

Comment: Does this code targets the screen dimension (actual size) or the screen resollution? It can be a really small phone but it can have a big resollution for example!